# Print without opening or downloading file?

Tags: sharepoint-online, printing, shortcut

Is there a simpler print method without opening or downloading SharePoint Document?

Comment: Excluding Windows Explorer is because need to compile printouts into a book according to Sharepoint view which can differ from Windows Explorer. Files are flowcharts containing extenal links. How to correlate external links to folder path ?

Answer (score 1):

There is no OOB solution to print file in SharePoint online document library without opening or downloading.

As a workaround, view in file explorer, you can print files in Windows Explorer:

[image]

Comment: Is file explorer view only available for OneDrive?

Comment: View in File Explorer available for SharePoint online in Microsoft Edge browser. Check [how to configure View in File Explorer with Microsoft Edge](https://ganeshsanapblogs.wordpress.com/2021/09/22/sharepoint-online-view-in-file-explorer-available-in-microsoft-edge/).